# iOS : Open a specific page through local notifications in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: ios, notifications, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm working on an **iOS** app in **Appcelerator Titanium** (SDK 3.5.1.GA) which uses a *background service* to display a *local iOS notification* when the app is in the background. Once the notification is tapped the app re-launches without issue, but I'm having trouble redirecting to a specific page when tapped on the notification. Please see my code below;

> Acquiring permissions for iOS 8 & above.

```
if (Ti.Platform.name == "iPhone OS" && parseInt(Ti.Platform.version.split(".")[0]) >= 8) {
    Ti.App.iOS.registerUserNotificationSettings({
        types : [Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT, Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND, Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE]
    });
}
```

> Registering background service.

```
var notificationsService = Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({
    url : 'services/backgroundService.js'
});
```

> In backgroundService.js

```
var notification = Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
  alertBody:"Hi, you have a new notification!",
  date:new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5000)
}); // shows notification after 5 seconds of background time.

Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener('notification', function(e) {
    var loginWindow = require('/newLogin');
    var win_login = loginWindow.getLoginWindow();
    win_login.open();
});
```

Once the *'notification'* event-listener is triggered, the *win_login* screen will be displayed for a mere 2 seconds and disappear (the app will then display the home page).

Can anybody tell me what I can do differently to make it work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your app is executing the code from your newLogin window but after a second it keeps loading what it should load from the app.js file.
You can either set a Global variable like "comingFromNotification" and after all stuff the app does on app.js check this variable and open the window or add a timeout function

Comment: Thanks! Adding the 'notification' event listener to app.js solved this.